# Jquery count specific character in div

Tags: jquery

I have a php code that generates some `<a>` tags and the final output looks like:

```
<div id='link1'>
<a style="font-size:10pt; color: #008056" href="somelink">Name</a>
<b>;</b>
</div>
```

My question is how can I count all of the semicolons in that div with jquery?

Comment: Including those in the `style` attribute? Also, why on earth do you need this?

Comment: I upvoted @RoryMcCrossan as I am eager to hear an explanation behind this problem.

Comment: `$('div').html().split(';').length`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Each link represents an author's name for a product. Some products have more than 1 author and a ; is put after each name. I want to count those ; and if there is only one I'd like to remove it.

Comment: In that case counting the number of `a` elements in the div will be more reliable and faster.

Comment: @user986959 from your above comments you could probably use [$('#link1').children('b:last-child').remove()](http://jsfiddle.net/9dxbF/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get including those in the style attribute,Try this:

```
  alert($('#link1').html().split(";").length - 1);
```

And to get without one that are there in attributes:

```
  alert($('#link1').html().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").split(";").length - 1);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xwvGC/1/)**

**Update:** To find one occurence of `;` in a and remove it:

```
$('#link1 a').each(function(){
 if($(this).html().split(";").length==2){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(";",""))
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xwvGC/3/)**

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you are up to, but if you need it, then you can do:

```
$('#link1').html().match(/;/g).length
```

`/;/g` is the regex that will match all `;`